# ACF + сравнение товаров

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, acf

Есть сайт на WordPress на нем реализован каталог товаров с помощью пользовательских типов записей + ACF произвольные поля, с помощью которых заполняются различные параметры. В шаблон все выводится с помощью Relationship field + $query = new WP_Query. Появилась необходимость реализовать сравнение товаров примерно как здесь https://fxtraders.info/ru/compare/

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

Если создать html шаблон, вывести в него три товара, то как дать пользователю возможность самому выбирать товары для сравнения из БД без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: спасибо, как подключить аякс почитаю, а вот как реализовать с его помощью подобный функционал, пока не понятно

Comment: Так и реализовывать. По нажатию на кнопку вызывать через ajax код php, проводить в нем сравнение товаров, и результат возвращать в js. С помощью js менять содержимое таблицы сравнения на странице.

Comment: KAGG-Design - может для вас это очевидно и просто, но я не очень силен в ajax и если бы вы подробнее рассказали, а лучше на примере показали, было бы лучше

Comment: Без вашего минимального кода любой пример будет иметь академический характер. Такой же, как на сайте kama. Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: И да - в вашем примере должна быть показана попытка что-то сделать самому. С указанием конкретных проблем, что именно не получается.